# Video player controls (Play/Pause etc.) display as overlay

Tags: air, flex4, flash-builder, overlay, video-player

I am creating a custom video player in flash builder using SDK 4.1 on windows 7.

I have created video player controls like Play/Pause, progress bar etc. in a HBox.

Now I want to display these controls when user mouse hover on display object as overlay like in [vimeo.com](http://www.vimeo.com/) video player and remove/disable when hover out.

My current .mxml page structure is like http://i48.tinypic.com/15x4w7a.png

I simply show/hide video player controls HBox on video container mouse hover event by giving HBox height.

How can I implement overlay functionality in video player?

Any web link and source code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use states, and then assign the mouse move event to load "state 2" over 400ms, and mouse off event loads "state 1" again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use a Flex container that will allow content to be layered on top of other content. By design, the `VBox` and `HBox` containers do not allow this. They layout their contents in a vertical or horizontal layout with no overlap.

You can use the `Canvas` or `Group` containers to overlay components on top of other components. Since you are using Flex 4, I would recommend using `Group` instead of `Canvas` ... and `VGroup` instead of `VBox` ... and `HGroup` instead of `HBox`.

Here is a simple layout you could do using the Flex 4 classes:

```
<s:Group>
    <s:VideoDisplay top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0" />
    <s:HGroup bottom="0" left="0" right="0"/>
</s:Group>
```

The `VideoDisplay` component is whatever you are using to show the video. Note that the top/bottom/left/right attributes tell the parent `Group` object to layout this component so that its top is 0 pixels from the parent's (Group's) top edge (and similar for the bottom/left/right edges).

The `HGroup` component is the container that holds your player controls. The `HGroup` is positioned to be 0 pixels from the bottom, left, and right edges of the parent container.

Instead of changing the height of the player controls container on mouseover, you should set the visible property `HGroup` (or `HBox`) container to false.

As they say, a picture is worth a thousand words. But on StackOverflow, code is worth a thousand pictures. If this answer doesn't help, you should edit your question and add the actual code you're using :)

Comment: Many thanks for answering. I will remember to post code instead of image next time. Thanks

Comment: @vkwave No worries! I didn't mean to sound condescending or anything like that ... sometimes a picture helps a lot to explain things that are hard to describe. Generally, showing the code cuts right to the chase and will prevent people from suggesting common things that you may have already tried. Cheers! :)